# Will a Cat6 patch panel work with Cat6a cable?

Tags: networking, wiring, cat6

I have a CAT6 patch panel I received as a gift from a non-techie person. They also bought me CAT6a cable. Can I use the CAT6 patch panel and fully benefit from CAT6a or do I need to upgrade to a CAT6a patch panel (as I see these are sold)?

Comment: The category of any cable system is the category of the lowest rated component of the system. It is highly doubtful, unless you have a lot of experience (which I doubt based on your question) and a very, very expensive tester, that you could install Category-6 or Category-6A cabling and get it to actually pass the required test suite to be certified. Also, the patch panels should be for solid-core cable, so you need to make sure that you don't have stranded cable to try to use with it. Solid-core is for horizontal cable, and stranded is for patch cords, and terminations must match.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I have solid core cable. And should I not run cat6a at all if I don't have the expensive testers?

Comment: You can use Category-6 or 6A, but I doubt you can terminate them in such a way as to pass the respective test suites without an expensive tester; it usually take experience cable installer a fair bit of practice to do this. You may be able to do it yourself and get gigabit to work, or not, but then why waste the money since those categories are designed to be able to run 10 gigabit, and I don't think you could pull that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with network wiring before, but it's been a while so I had to look it up. It seems highly unlikely that you could use your Cat6 patch panel with Cat6A cables. The overall diameter of Cat6A cables as well as the conductor gauge are significantly different - the two most important factor for termination compatibility.
In other words, your cables won't fit.
Of course, you're welcome to try. :) You already have all the hardware.

From http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=80036

> CAT 6A cable is considerably different from previous generation cable.
>   Its larger outside diameter (OD), corresponding larger minimum bend
>   radius, and heavier weight will change installation requirements for
>   routing and handling as well as design of pathways and spaces. How is
>   CAT 6A Cable Unique? • TIA standard allows up to .354" outside
>   diameter (OD), a 54% increase over CAT 6 OD average of .23" • More
>   than twice the weight of typical CAT 6 cable • Tighter twists and
>   larger conductor size than CAT 6 and 5e

Comment: Okay great thanks for this but in regards to standards it should work correct, like for example you don't benefit from cat6 cable in a cat5 patch panel